# How to prevent conflicts while multiple python scripts accessing MySQL DB at once ?

Tags: python, mysql

I have MySQL DB/table with column "name" containing one value. Multiple python scripts are accessing the same DB/table and the same column. There are also two more columns called "locked" and "locked_by", each script is reading the table and selects 10 entries from "name" where "locked" is false and update the locked value to True so other script can't take them and do the same work again. At least that is the solution I have for multiple script accessing one column and not tripping all over each other.. BUT!

I'm worried that between time when one script is updating the "locked" status other script takes that value and try to update it and so on.. ending in mess

Is there some solution to this or am I just worried about non exitant issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SQLs: `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` would lock the selected row and other processes can't read/update it until I commit changes.. if I understand correctly